# Just found the Python DBF package upgrade to dbf 0.97.0, who knows what's new in this upgrade?

Tags: python, dbf

There isn't any relevant document found from the webpage. thanks a lot for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to a single code-base approach.  I had had it split between 2.x, 3.0-2, and 3.3+ because I liked some of the enhancements in 3.3, but it was too big a headache trying to keep three versions in sync.

Edit:  I also changed from using the strings `'read-only'` and `'read-write'` for opening databases to the constants `dbf.READ_ONLY` and `dbf.READ_WRITE`.

0.97.001 now supports opening databases as read-only even when the files are read-only (yes, that was a bug.)